# MalformedJsonException using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am trying to get a JSON response from server in my Android app. I am using this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {

            @Override
            public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                com.squareup.okhttp.Response respuesta = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                Log.i("David", "Respuesta body: " + respuesta.body().string());
                return respuesta;
            }
        });
        Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

With this interface method:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST ("login")
Call<JSONObject> login(@Header("x-imei") String imei, @Field("usuario") String user, @Field("password") String password, @Header("Accept") String accept, @Header("Content-Type") String content);
```

And this call:

```
Call<JSONObject> peticion=interfaz.login(imei, user, encriptedPass, "application/json", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

This way, I am getting a MalformedJsonException in the Log:

```
[{"coderror":"-1","gravedad":"0","message":"com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 9","cause":"com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 9"}]
```

I am not able to see the JSON to check what is wrong with it.

The strange part is if I use curl this way:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" -H "x-id-cliente:demos" -H "x-imei:xxxxxxxxx" --data "{usuario: ‘user', password: ‘password'}" "https://my/server/url/api/login"
```

I get the JSON ok. What am I doing wrong? Why the curl is ok, but not the code call?

Thank you.

Comment: FormUrlEncoded( which sends data as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) ???? with `Content-Type: application/json` ... please decide for one ...

Comment: If I don't set it, I receive a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding.

Comment: then do not use `@Field` parameter ... please find some tutorial how to send json with Retrofit 2 ...

Comment: I cannot send it using JSON. It needs to be sent in the Request as a parameter. That is how things are settled in the server.

Comment: *I cannot send it using JSON*  huh ? but your curl's version is just sending the json string as body of the HTTP POST request (with some custom headers)

Comment: --data sends the parameters as JSON? I thought it sends the parameters in the request.

Comment: it send data .... doesn't matter in what format ... `{usuario: ‘user', password: ‘password'}` is a json string ... that's what it sends ... using application/x-www-form-urlencoded would send `usuario=user&password=password` which obviously is not json ... and server expects json ....

Comment: I will search an appropriate tutorial to send JSON...thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: Its not laziness. Its ignorance. Not everybody knows everything about every matter, as you seem to do. Thats why I am asking.